# Can't seem to get JSON data in code

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, azure-cognitive-services

So I have a JSON coming in from Microsoft cognitive services but somehow I just can't get it to work in my code. Am I doing something wrong?

I tried to do things like `JSON[0].emotion` and many variations but just can't get it right. Hope someone can help me out.

[Screenshot of JSON coming in (web console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YANG3.png)

Comment: Make sure to wrap your JSON data in `JSON.parse()` to evaluate it, if it's in string form.

Comment: It should be `data[0].faceAttributes.emotion`.

Comment: or.... json[0].faceRectangle.faceAttributes.emotion.anger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, you need to parse a JSON before using it:

```
var myJson = JSON.parse( YOUR_JSON_HERE );
console.log(myJson);
```

`myJson` should now be an object or array of object depending on the JSON received.